Cech cohomology cap product
This is a rephrasing of a recent post I made, then swiftly deleted. I am reading this paper, where on page 95 it is mentioned that if $X$ is a closed oriented manifold and $K \subseteq X$ is a closed submanifold, then we have a cap product
\begin{align*}
\hat{H}^p(K) \otimes H_n(X, X-K) \rightarrow H_q(X, X-K).
\end{align*}
(where $p+q = n$). I am wondering if more generally, we have a cap product
\begin{align*}
\hat{H}^p(K) \otimes H_{p+q}(X, X-K) \rightarrow H_q(X, X-K),
\end{align*}
even when $p+q < n$. If so, where can I learn more?

Skimming the linked doc I don't see any reason why this should only work for $p + q = n$: Certainly the construction of the relative cap product doesn't use this assumption, and compatibility with restriction also works in general; but I haven't checked everything in detail.
